# How to filter HashMap using stream in proper way?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `HashMap`. I would like to filter this `HashMap` using three separate methods.
In my `HashMap` I have three positions: from, by, to.

The first method should filter my `HashMap` using for example: from.
If I choose a `"city1"` the method should display only all connections where `from ='city1'`

The second method should filter my `HashMap` using for example: by. This method and stream should displays
all connections where `by ="city2"` or for example empty `string = ""` in that case

The third method should filter my `HashMap` using for example: `to ="city3"`
If I choose a `"city3"` the method should display only all connections where `to ='city3'`

The fourth method display all `HashMap` - it works fine.

```
public static Map<Integer, City> getAllCitiesMap() {
            Map<Integer, City> allCitiesMap = new HashMap<Integer, City>();
            allCitiesMap.put(0,new City("city1","", "city2"));
            allCitiesMap.put(1,new City("city1","city2", "city4"));
            allCitiesMap.put(2,new City("city1", "","city5"));
            allCitiesMap.put(3,new City("city1", "city2","city7"));
            allCitiesMap.put(4,new City("city2","", "city1"));
            allCitiesMap.put(5,new City("city2", "city1","city8"));
            allCitiesMap.put(6,new City("city2", "","city6"));
            allCitiesMap.put(7,new City("city2", "","city5"));
            allCitiesMap.put(8,new City("city2", "","city4"));
            allCitiesMap.put(9,new City("city2", "","city7"));
            

            return allCitiesMap;
        }



public class City {

      private static String from;
      private static String by;
      private static String to;

    public City(String from, String by, String to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.by = by;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public static String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
    public static String getBy() { return by; }
    public static String getTo() {
        return to;
    }
```

I did four methods but these methods don't display and don't filter what I would like to see. Only the fourth method works fine.
How to do it, improve a code below?

1.

```
public static void findAllConnectionFromOneCity(){
    
        AllCities.getAllCitiesMap().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(c -> City.getFrom().equals("city1"))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

2. 

```
public static void findAllConnectionToOneCity(){

    AllCities.getAllCitiesMap().entrySet().stream()
            .filter(c -> City.getBy().equals("city1"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

3. ```
           public static void filterCities(Map<Integer, String> allCitiesMap){
             Map<Integer, String> filteredCitiesMap =
                     allCitiesMap.entrySet()
                             .stream()
                             .filter(s -> City.getTo().equals("city1"))
                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                              Map.Entry::getValue));

              }
   ```

4. 

```
 public static void findAllCities(){

        AllCities.getAllCitiesMap().entrySet().stream()
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling `City.getFrom()` and not `c.getFrom()`?

Comment: Are the getters in your classes defined as static? Because otherwise I don't even see how your code is compiling

Comment: Is `City.getFrom` a static method? Can you show how you've defined the City class?

Comment: @Ayyoub yes, getters are defined as static.

Comment: What is this Flight class ??

Comment: What made you define your getters as static?

Comment: Can you also post the definition of City and Flight classes?

Comment: I have just updated my question.

Comment: Design of your solution isn't the best one.. implementation is not a much problem.. you can fix it easily, but first of all, think about what you want to achieve and how to design it in a KISS and DRY manner.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not define `setters` and `getters` as static. They are the means to access object fields and shouldn't be static. 

 More on it here .. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Since you have a `Map` where you have kept all your `City` objects, you should be creating a stream on the values of the `map` rather than the keys:

```
public static void findAllConnectionFromOneCity(){    
    AllCities.getAllCitiesMap().entrySet().stream()
            .filter(c -> City.getFrom().equals("city1"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If there's no specific reason to keep the `City` objects in `Map`, you should change the data structure to a `List` and you can then use something like this to access the information

```
public static void findAllConnectionFromOneCityList() {
    AllCities.getAllCities().stream().filter(c -> c.getFrom().equals("city1"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Neither should the fields be `static`. Note that `entrySet().stream()` will create a stream of `Map.Entry` objects. If you want to stream over the values, just use `values().stream()` instead. But there is no point in using a `Map` with ascending numbers as key at all. That’s what `List` is for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work on your design. You are making use of a `Map` without harnessing it's key-value functionality. In such cases, you can think of choosing `List` as suggested by fellow community members. However I can point out what might be going wrong with your existing code.

It can be observed that `filter` method is called directly on the `entrySet()` and you are trying to filter cities. But actually at this point `filter` method will have `Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, City>>` and NOT `Stream<City>` itself. Hence, you should convert the stream to `Stream<City>` first before filtering.

```
allCitiesMap.entrySet().stream()
.map(entry -> entry.getValue())
.filter(city -> city.getFrom().equals("city1"))
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or

You can also make use of `Map.values()` as:

```
allCitiesMap.values().stream()
    .filter(city -> city.getFrom().equals("city1"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Instead of `entrySet().stream().map(entry -> entry.getValue())` you can use `values().stream()` in the first place.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. I just pointed out the mistake that OP was doing. Included the suggested solution also in the answer.

Comment: I have just checked and these two solutions don't work. They don't display results.